# working with Urlsession inside today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget, xcode8

I don't understand why completion block is not worked. First I find current location, then I use latitude and longitude to get data from server. I also tried with background Session using NSURLSessionDelegate but also don't get any data.

```
- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    [self updateWidget];
    self.placeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image"];
    self.crowdednessLevelImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle-crowd"];
    self.placeImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] initWithSuiteName:@"group.wherepeeps.mostCrowdedPlace.widgert"];
    NSString *coordinateString = [defaults objectForKey:@"CurrentLocationCoordinateString"];
    NSDictionary *responseObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"listOfPlacesForWidget"];
    NSLog(@"responseObject - %@", responseObject);
    if (coordinateString) {
        NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://sheltered-fjord-29765.herokuapp.com/api/v1/search?location=%@", coordinateString];
        NSURLSession *mySession = [self configureMySession];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
        [mySession dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSDictionary *responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] initWithSuiteName:@"group.wherepeeps.mostCrowdedPlace.widgert"];
            [defaults setObject:responseObject forKey:@"listOfPlacesForWidget"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            NSLog(@"responseObject - %@", responseObject);
            completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
        }];     

    } else {
        completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNoData);
    }   
}

- (NSURLSession *)configureMySession {
    if (!self.mySession) {
       // NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.mycompany.myapp.backgroundsession"];
        NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        // To access the shared container you set up, use the sharedContainerIdentifier property on your configuration object.
        config.sharedContainerIdentifier = @"com.mycompany.myappgroupidentifier";
        self.mySession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    }
    return self.mySession;
}
```

Comment: `dataTaskWithURL:` returns a task that you have to call `resume` on.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Nsurlsession request on main thread with persormSelectorOnMainThread.